# MVC Razor: How to mix html helpers and text in same line?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to use multiple html helpers in the same line, but I'm not succeding.

The result I search is: `Name:<textbox>` (note the ":")

```
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Name) ":" @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name) //doesn't work
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: Define 'doesnt work'; do you get a compiler exception, or just not the intended outcome? That code looks perfectly valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `@:` syntax.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Name) @:: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
}
```

Or the special tag `text` (this tag is not rendered, it allows you to put text between codes like this)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Name) <text>:</text> @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the quotes around the `:`

Razor should stop looking for code after the closing parenthsis, so you don't need to specify that it is a string.

```
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Name): @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
```

Comment: `:` is considered as a piece of code and it turns out in an invalid syntax.